# How can I display a Linkedin feed on my website

Tags: javascript, request, linkedin-api

I would like to show my company Linkedin feed on my website (not a WordPress site), how can I do that through a network request?
Should I use this API as a reference? https://linkedin.api-docs.io/v1.0/feed/WGWyNnXsNraWdokv9

Comment: Your link is not working.